# Why react-flatpickr does not render?

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

Why does Flatpickr component from react-flatpickr does not render at all?

I created a React component that renders the `<Flatpickr />` component with some additional options. The component is rendered but the`<Flatpickr />` does not render at all. When using the `<Flatpickr />` component in another file it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone has the same issue:

Make sure you import correctly

```
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr'
```

from `react-flatpickr` and not `flatpickr`.